# Where can I find the most up-to-date apt-get package list for my distribution?

Tags: apt, aptitude

In other words, is there a website where I can find a simple list of all the packages that apt-get install searches through, along with descriptions of what each package does?

When I run apt-get update, I see that my computer hits http://security.ubuntu.com and finds something called oneiric-updates. Is there a human-friendly version of this website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all the packages depending on the build installed here:

[Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)

But Oneiric Ocelot is the Codename for 11.10, so it is probably just downloading the security updates for your version.  I wouldn't be worried about anything.

EDIT: After looking here: 
[Ubuntu oneiric-updates](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+milestone/oneiric-updates). It possibly looks like a pack of drivers but I may be mistaken

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "human-friendly"

You can browse here:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is software manager.

It has GUI and categorized package lists. It is in your ubuntu by default. Try may be.